# Garbage Code showing in code in server but not in localhost : OPECART

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, opencart

Hi i have this weird little problem it is that i have this

Code `��/�(����R��V�HML��K�/�,�IU�U�UP�.�I-R�M�+U�)��`

showing up on the header of my website 
http://vebizsolutions.com/demo/dev1/cart4/index.php

But it does not show on localhost.

I have tried to locate it by:

1. Tried to find it in DATABASE
2. Tried to search in the whole code
3. Updating the fonts

How do I locate the problem?

**header.tpl**

```
<div class="links"> <!-- <a href="<?php echo $wishlist; ?>" id="wishlist-total" class="icon-wishlist-white"><?php echo $text_wishlist; ?></a> <a href="<?php echo $account; ?>" id="link-account" class="icon-user-white"><?php echo $text_account; ?></a> <a href="<?php echo $shopping_cart; ?>" id="link-cart" class="icon-cart-white"><?php echo $text_shopping_cart; ?></a> <a href="<?php echo $checkout; ?>" id="link-checkout" class="icon-checkout-white"><?php echo $text_checkout; ?></a>  -->
            <!-- Meus -->
            <?php if ($this->config->get("kuler_menu_status")) { ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChild("module/kuler_menu"); ?>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <!-- Menu -->
            </div>
```

Comment: Open up your `catalog/view/theme/<CURRENT_THEME>/template/common/header.tpl` and post the code that is inside of `<div class="links">{CODE}</div>`. And IMHO, You should disable that product image zoom effect (on mouse hover), I almost puked myself and now I have a headache...

Comment: @shadyyx i have added header.tpl

Comment: The output is coming from this call `<?php echo $this->getChild("module/kuler_menu"); ?>` - can you identify where is it coming from? Some third-party extension? Can you inspect it?

Comment: @shadyyx i know it is coming from here but it is no where to be found is there any work around from this or something

Comment: No workaround. You need to find that extension's files (controller, template, language file, etc.) and inspect them. That text is coming from that extension. Maybe you also did some custom modifications to this extension? If you find it it would be worth checking the file encoding (should be UTF-8 - if it isn't, make sure to change it).

Comment: @shadyyx it is not in my code and my document is utf-8

Comment: I can't help you more then.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

There was no problem with the website it was a server problem when i switched the server it automatically does not show it thats it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here's what I get in Firefox: `"Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /hsphere/local/home/c279011/vebizsolutions.com/demo/dev1/cart4/catalog/controlle‌​r/module/ebaydisplay.php on line 19"`.

Perhaps you should examine the code in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Here, issue in your language(header.php) file. I think, You have modified language file.
May be in this files(catalog\language\your language\common\header.php)

When you will any changes in language files. So, You need to save files in utf-8 encoding.

Make sure that your php file is saved in utf-8 encoding (See here: notepad++ converting ansi encoded file to utf-8 OR here http://www.herongyang.com/Unicode/Notepad-Save-File-in-UTF-8.html) :)